# How to add ssl cipher to ssl_ciphers in nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, encryption, lets-encrypt

I am using Let's Encrypt to install a free TLS/SSL certificate in my server. I followed the suggestion of [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) and configured nginx like this:

```
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
```

The problem is that I need Java 7 to communicate with the server and it doesn't work with the configuration above.

When I submit my site to [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) I get the following message:

```
Java 7u25   Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

---

If I just comment the ssl_ciphers line in nginx configuration, than the communication with Java 7 starts to work.

```
# After commenting the line below it works
# ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
```

So I get the following message from [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html):

```
Java 7u25   RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.0 TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

---

I would not like to let the ssl_ciphers line commented, because nginx would use its default configuration, which is less secure.

I would like just to add the cipher TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA to the ssl_ciphers list.

Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [OpenSSL's cipher list](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html) or [this nice table from testssl.sh](https://testssl.sh/openssl-rfc.mapping.html), `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` corresponds to `ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA`. So you'd set your `ssl_ciphers` directive to

`ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA";`

Answer (score 0):

Find the canonical name with

```
openssl ciphers -tls1_2 -stdname -V   | grep TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
      0xC0,0x27 - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
      0xC0,0x13 - TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    TLSv1 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
```

Now you can explicitly exclude it from the nginx config with

```
ssl_ciphers 'HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA';
```