# java version "1.7.0_171" to support ciphersuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384

Tags: java, encryption, https

I am using java version

```
java version "1.7.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (amzn-2.6.13.0.76.amzn1-x86_64 u171-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.171-b01, mixed mode)
```

when i try to call a `HTTPS` webservice I got `exception`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported ciphersuite TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.valueOf(CipherSuite.java:235)
    at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuiteList.<init>(CipherSuiteList.java:82)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setEnabledCipherSuites(SSLSocketImpl.java:2413)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
```

the server ssl connection using `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`

this is the server information

```
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api..... (1xx.2xx.1xx.1xx) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=api.....
*   start date: Apr 27 09:29:11 2018 GMT
*   expire date: Jul 26 09:29:11 2018 GMT
*   common name: api.server1.ih.testenv.io
*   issuer: CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: api.server1.ih.testenv.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.53.1
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
< Date: Thu, 03 May 2018 08:43:05 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 39
< Connection: keep-alive
< cache-control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< x-request-id: 2klhbq0t5ahtlndlmc0003k2
```

how can i support this ciphersuite ?

EDIT: I cannot upgrade to java 8

Comment: `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` is supported in Java 8 and onwards. I don't know of any way to support this Cipher Suite in Java 7 other than relying on an external security provider. Compare https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html for a list of supported Cipher Suites (replace 7 with 8 for java 8 instead of 7)

Comment: This ciphersuite is supported from JDK 7u191, which is not free however https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/javase7supportreleasenotes-1601161.html#R170_191

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` and most other `GCM` cipher suites are not supported by the default security provider found in Java 7. Support for those was added in Java 8.

You can compare the specification and supported cipher suites for [Java 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) and [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) for confirmation here.

As your edit suggests that you can not upgrade to Java 8 at this point I don't think you have many choices other than using an external security provider.

An example would be the

> Legion of the Bouncy Castle Java cryptography APIs

which include a security provider for both the JCE and the JCA. Using an external security provider obviously means dealing with their licensing model, which for Bouncy Castle is quite simple though as they use a slightly adapted version of the MIT License.

There are good tutorials out there how to change the default security provider for Java, a quick search should help here.

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug this problem try to add "-Djavax.net.debug=ssl" when running your client application.

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl com.sample.Test
```

or by command line using OpenSSL:

```
openssl s_client -cipher 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384' -connect api.server:443
```

If you have control/access to the server, try to add this cipher on the server side.

- Apache SSLCipherSuite: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html

If you are using NGinx:
    [How to add ssl cipher to ssl_ciphers in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400578/how-to-add-ssl-cipher-to-ssl-ciphers-in-nginx)

### Caution

> In some environments, certain algorithms or key lengths may be
>   undesirable when using SSL/TLS.  This section describes the mechanism
>   for disabling algorithms during SSL/TLS security parameters
>   negotiation, including protocol version negotiation, cipher suites
>   selection, peer authentication and key exchange mechanisms.

- To determine the default value for the property "jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms" and the syntax, check the "jre/lib/security/java.security" file

Please also check this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758303/problems-connecting-via-https-ssl-through-own-java-client):